# Asset doesn't load in prod

Tags: javascript, symfony, assetic

I'm using slick.js to display a carousel. Everything works fine in dev, but it seems like the resource doesn't load in prod. I'm loading my assets like this :

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {% javascripts
    '@MyUILayerBundle/Resources/public/vendor/jquery/1.11.1/jquery-1.11.1.min.js'
    '@MyUILayerBundle/Resources/public/vendor/handlebars/1.3.0/handlebars-v1.3.0.js'
    '@MyUILayerBundle/Resources/public/vendor/underscorejs/1.6.0/underscore-min.js'
    '@MyUILayerBundle/Resources/public/vendor/jquery.cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie-1.4.1.min.js'
    '@MyUILayerBundle/Resources/public/vendor/jquery-ui/1.11.0/js/jquery-ui.min.js'
    '@MyUILayerBundle/Resources/public/vendor/moment/min/moment-with-locales.min.js'
    '@MyUILayerBundle/Resources/public/vendor/alertify/0.3.11/js/alertify.min.js'
    '@MyUILayerBundle/Resources/public/vendor/select2/3.5.0/select2.min.js'
    '@MyUILayerBundle/Resources/public/vendor/select2/3.5.0/select2_locale_fr.js'
    '@MyUILayerBundle/Resources/public/vendor/oboe/oboe-browser.js'
    '@MyUILayerBundle/Resources/public/vendor/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js'
    '@MyUILayerBundle/Resources/public/vendor/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js'
    '@MyUILayerBundle/Resources/public/vendor/jquery-json/jquery-json.js'
    '@MyUILayerBundle/Resources/public/vendor/slick/slick.js'
    '@MyUILayerBundle/Resources/public/vendor/typeahead/typeahead.js'
    output='bundles/main.js'
    %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{  asset_url }}">
    </script>

    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

and in another file, I'm using this :

```
$('.multiple-items').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3
});
```

for some reason, the carousel works fine in dev, but I get an error in prod, saying that slick() is not a function.

Any idea why ?

Comment: have you remembered to dump the assets? `php app/console assetic:dump`

Comment: yes I did, didn't change anything

Comment: did you dump you assets with the prod environment and clear your cache? `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug`   `php bin/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug`